# Regex extract string based on String match

Tags: regex

I have this data with some messy addresses inside which contains sometimes not in order a Province, District, and ward :

```
Name        ADDRESS 
Store1      453, Duy Tan, Phuong Nguyen Nghiem, Thanh pho Quang Ngai
Store2      13 DUNG SY THANH KHE, P. THANH KHE TAY
Store3      98 Phan Xich Long- P. 2
Store4      306 B4, NGUYENVAN LINH, Ward - 5 
Store5      22, Ngo 421/16, Tran Duy Hung, To 42, Phuong Trung Hoa, Quan Cau Giay




    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        //Replace each \ with \\ so that C# doesn't treat \ as escape character
        //Pattern: Start of string, any integers, 0 or 1 letter, end of word
        string sPattern = "^[0-9]+([A-Za-z]\\b)?";
        string sString = Row.ADDRESS ?? ""; //Coalesce to empty string if NULL

        //Find any matches of the pattern in the string
        Match match = Regex.Match(sString, sPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //If a match is found
        if (match.Success)
            //Return the first match into the new
            //HouseNumber field
            Row.ward= match.Groups[0].Value;
        else
            //If not found, leave the HouseNumber blank
            Row.ward= "";
    }

}
```

I would like to modify my regex formula to return the data like this in the column Ward. (you can see the synonyms in my addresses (Phuong,P.,ward,etc).

```
Name         ADDRESS                                                                  ward 
Store1      453, Duy Tan, Phuong Nguyen Nghiem, Quang Ngai                Phuong Nguyen Nghiem
Store2      13 DUNG SY THANH KHE, P. THANH KHE TAY                        Phuong THANH KHE TAY
Store3      98 Phan Xich Long- P. 2                                       Phuong 2
Store4      306 B4, NGUYENVAN LINH, Ward - 5                              Phuong 5
Store5      22, Ngo 421/16,--. To 42, Phuong Trung Hoa, Quan Cau Giay     Phuong Trung Hoa
```

I use that regex expression to extract the civic number, but is there a way with REGEX i can modifiu return the data in my column ward like in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groups in this regex, as tested in https://regex101.com/, match the data in your column `ward`, as in your example. However, you may need to better define the patterns where each will appear since this regex only matches them as they appear in your example data. However, it may be enough for you to extrapolate and get the regex that you really need.

```
(Phuong.*),|P\.(.*$)|Ward - (.*$)
```

- The group in option 1 matches from `Phuong` (inclusive) until the first comma.
- The group in option 2 matches anything that comes after `P.` until the end of the string.
- The group in option 3 matches anything that comes after `Ward -`  until the end of the string.

This one is a bit more advanced, but it only matches what you mentioned in your examples, no groups:

```
Phuong.*(?=,)|(?<=P\.).*$|(?<=Ward - ).*$
```

Test it in https://regex101.com to see how it works and to see what each part means.

Finally, you may want to exclude `Phuong`  from the match in option 1 on so that your program can always print `Phuong`  and then the match.

Comment: Thanks for the help!